# how download pdf with wget and grep

Tags: pdf, grep, wget

I need to download pdf from html with wget and grep

`wget (link)`

`grep -Eo 'HREF="[^"]+\.pdf"' (file from wget)`

Result:

```
HREF="./slides/PA - intro python - bases algorithmiques.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PB - programmation modulaire avec python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PC - collections sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PD - classes sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PE - fichiers sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PG - vecteurs avec numpy.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PH - matrices avec numpy.pdf"
```

i need to download pdf only with wget and grep i can't use this :

`wget -A pdf  -r -l 1 (link)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut -f2 '-d"'` to get the second `"`-delimited field from the list of HREFs:

```
/v/f/n/8/T/tmp.lwgNOsXH $ cat > hrefs.txt

HREF="./slides/PA - intro python - bases algorithmiques.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PB - programmation modulaire avec python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PC - collections sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PD - classes sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PE - fichiers sous python.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PG - vecteurs avec numpy.pdf"
HREF="./slides/PH - matrices avec numpy.pdf"

/v/f/n/8/T/tmp.lwgNOsXH $ cut -f2 '-d"' hrefs.txt

./slides/PA - intro python - bases algorithmiques.pdf
./slides/PB - programmation modulaire avec python.pdf
./slides/PC - collections sous python.pdf
./slides/PD - classes sous python.pdf
./slides/PE - fichiers sous python.pdf
./slides/PG - vecteurs avec numpy.pdf
./slides/PH - matrices avec numpy.pdf

/v/f/n/8/T/tmp.lwgNOsXH $
```